# the value of Title property is not getting updated for jpg file using apache sanselan?

Tags: java, metadata

i want to update the metadata (like tag,comments etc.....) of .jpg & .tif files using JAVA 
can any one help me  ....

note :i have tried with the below code but when i chek the property of file using windows explorer the value of title is not updated

```
 public static void changeExifMetadata(File jpegImageFile, File dst)
                   throws IOException, ImageReadException, ImageWriteException {

   OutputStream os = null;
    try
     {   
TiffOutputSet outputSet = null;
IImageMetadata metadata = Sanselan.getMetadata(jpegImageFile);
JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) metadata;
if (null != jpegMetadata)
{
    TiffImageMetadata exif = jpegMetadata.getExif();

    if (null != exif)
    {
        outputSet = exif.getOutputSet();

    }else  {}
}
     if (null == outputSet)
    outputSet = new TiffOutputSet();
         {

    final TiffOutputDirectory exifDir = outputSet .getOrCreateExifDirectory();
    byte[] rawBytes = "KasperAuthor".getBytes("UTF-16LE"); 
    byte[] nullTerminatedBytes = new byte[rawBytes.length + 2]; 
    exifDir.removeField(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPTITLE);
TiffOutputField authorField = new TiffOutputField(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPTITLE, ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPTITLE.dataTypes[0], nullTerminatedBytes.length,  nullTerminatedBytes);                                                            
    exifDir.add(authorField);
}

 } finally
   {
if (os != null)
    try
    {
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

thanks in advance ....